# Refactoring a module and keeping backward compatibility, including for intersphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx, api-design

Given a python package `pack` providing the `pack.foo.Bar` class:

```
pack/
    __init__.py  # empty
    foo.py
        # content of foo.py
        """
        This module does stuff using the :class:`pack.foo.Bar` class.
        """

        class Bar(object):
            pass

        # much more code here
```

I want to refactor the `pack.foo` module into a package, so that the `Bar` class is moved to the `pack/foo/bar.py` file.  In order to keep backward compatibility, I can had this to the `pack/foo/__init__.py` file:

```
"""
This module does stuff using the :class:`pack.foo.Bar` class.
"""

from pack.foo.bar import Bar
__all__ = ['Bar']
```

Users of the API can still use `from pack.foo import Bar`.

One issue remains: references when using sphinx.  When sphinx parses the docstring in `pack/foo/__init__.py`, it can't find the target:

```
WARNING: py:class reference target not found pack.foo.bar.Bar
```

Which would break the documentation made by users when using the [intersphinx](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/intersphinx.html) extension.

What is the proper way of refactorying a package structure and still keep a full backward compatibility, including the sphinx object inventory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my own answer with some findings.

There is no silver bullet in this situation.

First, code documentation generated by [sphinx-apidoc](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/man/sphinx-apidoc.html) will have the module layout infered from the file layout.  This means that the `Bar` class defined in `pack/foo.py` will be documented as `pack.foo.Bar`, no matter what import mangling happens in `pack/__init__.py`.

Second, one can still use the [autodoc extension](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/autodoc.html).  Autodoc simply tries to import the documented symbols normaly as they are defined in restructured text.  This way, you could generate HTML documentation for the `Bar` class using

```
.. autoclass:: pack.Bar
    :members:
```

There is a catch though. Any documented symbol (and each of their dependencies, transitively) must be used with the exact same namespace that is intented to be documented.  Consider a variation of our example, providing an additional class `Baz`:

```
pack/
    __init__.py
        # content of __init__.py
        from pack.foo.bar import Bar, Baz
        __all__ = ['Bar', 'Baz']

    foo.py
        # content of foo.py
        """
        This module does stuff using the :class:`pack.foo.Bar` class.
        """

        class Bar(object):
            pass

        class Baz(Bar):  # Here, sphinx thinks that Baz inherits from
            pass         # pack.foo.Bar because Bar.__module__ is
                         # pack.foo in this context.
```

Sphinx will fail to import `pack.foo.Bar` since it is importable only as `pack.Bar` because of the content of `pack/__init__.py`.

In order to make this work, one must find a way to only use the exact import layout provided by the package's API in the API's code itself. This may be achievable, in our example for instance, by defining the `Bar` and `Baz` classes in separate files. Good luck and be wary of cyclic imports!